# In JavaScript, Is it good to declare an Array to store a single value just to facilitate iterating over it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have an object where it's keys can take a single value or array of values

```
Ex: sample = {}
sample[key] = "foo"
sample[bar] = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"]
```

I will eventually iterate over this object (**`sample`**) and output the values. In this process, I have to check if each value is an Array and if so I'll have to output those values.

Which is a costly operation?

Checking if the value is an array every time while iterating?

```
if(Array.isArray(arr[prop]))
```

**OR**

just make all the keys as arrays so that I can iterate with ease like,

```
arr[prop].forEach(function(val){}
```

Algorithmically, is declaring extra space to facilitate iterating over an object worth it?

Comment: Do you have an actual measured performance problem? If not just write the code so that it makes sense to you.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the performance, I'd just try to write the clearest code. In general, you should try to be consistent in your data types, so use arrays all the time rather than having to check the type every time you use it.

Comment: @Barmar I think your comment makes sense. Having a clear code is important. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a private object, then it doesn't really matter, but it's probably better to favor simple code.

If this is an *interface* object, i.e., something that is provided to you as a function argument or through other means, then the distinction *is* important.  If all the keys can be multi-valued then you should just make them arrays, because it makes the interface simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It's far simpler to just check the `length` - if it's `undefined`, the item is an object. If it's anything else, it's an array:

```
if (arr[prop].length) { /* arr[prop] is an array */ }
```

## EDIT

As stated in the comments, strings also have a `length` property, so you should use `Array.isArray`.

Comment: Strings have a `.length` property. `Set` does not have a `.length` property.

Comment: Sorry @guest271314, will fix.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set the property names where the value is an `Array` to a string beginning with the word `"array"`, and strings beginning with the word `"string"`, and variable declared to `-1` which are incremented and concatenated to the `"string"` and `"array"` default property names

```js
const arrayKey = "array"
const stringKey = "string"
let arrayIndex = -1
let stringIndex = -1

const sample = {}
sample[`${stringKey}${++stringIndex}`] = "foo"
sample[`${arrayKey}${++arrayIndex}`] = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"]
sample[`${stringKey}${++stringIndex}`] = "bar"
  
const setEntry = (o, key, index, value) => o[`${key}${++index}`] = value

const filterEntries = (o, prop) => 
  Object.entries(o).filter(([key]) => prop === key || key.includes(prop))
  .map(([,value]) => value)
  
setEntry(sample, arrayKey, arrayIndex, ["Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot"])

let arrays = filterEntries(sample, arrayKey)
let strings = filterEntries(sample, stringKey)
let [bar] = filterEntries(sample, stringKey + 1)

console.log(strings)
console.log(arrays)
console.log(sample["string0"])
console.log(sample["array0"])
console.log(sample["string1"])
console.log(sample["array1"])
console.log(bar)
```